# Long install script successful as root; npm and composer not found as non-root sudoer

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm building a script to install everything needed for MediaWiki in one command on CentOS. Starting with a completely minimal install, this builds Apache, PHP, and Node.js from source plus sets up all the other necessary things to have a MediaWiki install with all the bells and whistles. This works great when invoked by root. When invoked by a non-root sudoer it had some strange issues. All this code is available at the GitHub repo enterprisemediawiki/Meza1 (sorry, I don't have enough reputation on this site to post more than 2 links)

Basically the user calls one script, `install.sh`. This script calls several other scripts, such as `apache.sh`, `php.sh`, and `VE.sh`. `VE.sh` installs Node.js and Parsoid (part of MediaWiki's Visual Editor).

Within `VE.sh` simply running `npm install` worked just fine under root. Under a non-root sudoer an "npm not found" error was given. To attempt to fix this, instead of using the symlink to npm at `/usr/local/bin/npm` I used the direct link to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`. However, this resulted in a "node not found" error. To solve this a symlink was created to node (actual executable at `/usr/local/bin/node`) from `/usr/bin/node`. This made things work.

What could cause this to happen? Both `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` are in PATH by default. Adding a symlink from another place in PATH should have no effect, right?

A similar situation occurred first with Composer. The `composer.phar` file was moved to `/usr/local/bin/composer` per the documentation, such that it does not need to be invoked via `php composer.phar <params>` but instead just by `composer <params>`. This did not work, and instead during the initial install composer was always invoked by `php ~/sources/composer.phar <params>`.

Note that this only happens during the initial install, and that after the `install.sh` script is is done running then composer, npm and node can be accessed without any issues.

Some useful links:

- [VE.sh working for non-root](https://github.com/enterprisemediawiki/Meza1/blob/b7336a8953b4b6d8280e7aeae7274c73bdff0169/client_files/VE.sh)
- [VE.sh working just for root](https://github.com/enterprisemediawiki/Meza1/blob/9806025134a2aeb2c8477282ce4a4ae3618dc445/client_files/VE.sh)
- See the current #90 (some of this text taken from it)
- See the original issue #68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` can be configured to reset the PATH before running a command. In my /etc/sudoers for example I have th eline:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

which forces the PATH for commands.  See `man sudoers`.

Comment: Running `echo $PATH` I get a long PATH including /usr/local/bin. Then I created a script `test.sh` with just the command `echo $PATH`. Running this I get the same long PATH. Running it with sudo I get `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`. Crazy. Thank you.